# MS Access Append Query slow only on Wifi connection

Tags: ms-access, wifi

I’m using MS Access to insert 100 records into a table on a local SQL server.

When my PC connects via Ethernet to the server, the APPEND query runs in less than a second.

When the same PC connects via WiFi router to this server it takes more than 30 seconds.

Details:

1. PC: Core7 8G RAM running Win10, with all updates installed.
2. MS Access: Ms Access 2003 with all updates installed. I have also tried MS Access 2010.The APPEND query is:

`INSERT INTO dbo_tableA ( A, B, C ) SELECT tableB.X, tableB.Y, tableB.Z FROM tableB;`

These tables include only 3 indexed integers and a key field. There are no calculated fields and the database was compacted. The same results when using code docmd.runsql. The speed of a SELECT query over the WiFi is fast.

3. Server: Xeon 8G RAM running on Windows Server 2003 with SQL 2005, with all updates installed. No other users connected.
4. Network: The WiFi router includes a multiple ports switch. The Server is connected to this switch directly.

No one is currently connected to the Wifi . It’s a 5Ghz 802.11n. 
The speedtest.xfinity.com results 27Mbps download and 6Mbps upload when running on the Ethernet port and the same results on the WiFi.

Many thanks in advance for any response.

Comment: 1) I suspect you mean on your local network, but when referring to a local server it usually means on the same computer.  2) Where does the Access file reside? Is it on a network share... even if it is a mapped drive?  3) Despite the xfinity speedtest, I suspect that the bandwidth between SQL Server and the WiFi computer is not configured optimally, but this will be a router/network issue beyond the scope of a Stack Overflow question. 4) I suggest using another tool to execute and debug the SQL statement on the Server, like SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS), and to compare with Access.

Comment: 5) Check/compare network configuration on the client computer.  The WiFi and Ethernet network devices have their own configuration, including protocols and other details.

Comment: 1. Yes the SQL server is connected to the local network.
2. The access mdb file is located on a laptop and it runs from this laptop, it is not shared.
3. The wifi network seems to be fine since a SELECT query of thousands of records takes a second.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is, that you should never run a split database where the backend connects via WiFi. Always used a wired connection.

The reason is, that a WiFi connection may have nasty breaks which the database engine never was and still isn't designed for. Actually, your backend will most likely corrupt sooner or later if WiFi is used.

If Wifi must be used, install your frontend on a terminal server with a wired connection to the backend, and use *Remote Desktop* to run the frontend.

Comment: Avoiding WiFi altogether is the obvious, easiest solution, but the backend is SQL Server, not another Access database.  It is implied that the Access file is local, although I asked in my comment for clarification.  Connections to the SQL Server should be rather short lived and should easily tolerate intermittent connection disruptions... and should not be corrupted due to failed remote requests.  Access should not need to hold a continuous connection to the SQL Server, especially just for an insert statement.

Comment: @CPerkins, you are right, it should work; I missed the SQL Server detail. As you mention, the question is probably OT here.

Answer (score 1):

This is not so much an "answer" as it is some debugging hints.  This question really is off topic since it involves significant debugging, but I do have some hints that are too long for a comment.

Now I see that `[tableB]` is in the Access DB being inserted into SQL Server.  Access is likely generating many individual statements to insert the data rows one-by-one rather than executing a single query executed on the SQL Server.  How else could it do this, since the SQL Server can't see the Access table and there is no Access SQL statement for inserting multiple values?

To see what's really going on, I suggest using [ODBC Tracing](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/selvar/2007/11/10/odbc-tracing/).  It is not clear from that webpage, but if you have ODBC drivers installed for connecting to the SQL Server, then the utility "ODBC Data Source Administrator" will be installed.  Just click the Start button and type "ODBC..." and it should show "ODBC Data Sources (32-bit)" and possibly "ODBC Data Sources (64-bit)".  Use only the 32-bit, since Access will only be using those drivers.  Follow the other instructions to capture all of the SQL commands being sent to the server.

The only workaround that I can suggest now is to use VBA to generate your own multi-statement Transact-SQL text that you send to the server using ODBC Direct.  This would circumvent excessive statement generation and handling of Access.  To do this "correctly" (i.e. in the most efficient, secure way) will require an understanding of Transact-SQL, creating and handling server transactions, direct access to SQL tables vs parameterized procedures, etc.